# Grafana Dockerfile plugin version ignored

Tags: docker, plugins, grafana

I want to install a certain Grafana plugin via the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM grafana/grafana:7.5.10

USER grafana

RUN /usr/share/grafana/bin/grafana-cli plugins install grafana-simple-json-datasource 1.4.2
```

After starting the container and calling `grafana-cli plugins ls`, I get version `1.4.0`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you build image and did you start container from that new built image? (BTW: grafana can install plugins from env variable `GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-simple-json-datasource 1.4.2` - that seems to be better option if container has internet access)

Comment: Yes, I called sudo docker build -t mygr:1.0.1 .  - The environment variable works for a new container. But for an exisiting container this is unfortunately ignored :-( -

Comment: Of course existing containers are running from old image. You need to completly stop existing container and start it from the scratch from new image.

Comment: Ok, usually I have an mounted external drive and kill the container after each run. Meanwhile I worked around with another image / container and managed to transfer the data file to the new container and install all necessary plugins via GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS. I'm still not sure what happened, but now it works. So thank you for  the hint. Is there any answer to the original question, i.e. defining a Dockerfile to provide the necessary plugins?